# Flutter Chart with Icons as measure Axis with charts_flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, format, icons, flutter-plugin

Imagine a chart with satisfaction smileys on the vertical axis.
How can we format any axis and replace values by icons with charts_flutter plugin?

Thank you!